# Как удалить ведущий "0" из строки?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть строка которая соединяет 2 строки в себя, мне нужно если 1-цифра 0 то удалить ее из строки. Как такое можно сделать?

Comment: А если там два нуля - удалить только первый?

Comment: @Akina уже решил, возможен только 0 нуль в начале строки

Comment: "1-цифра" должно означать "первая цифра"?

Comment: @Эникейщик Если первая цифра в строке 0 то удалять ее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил с помощью

```
String str = "04654"
str = str.replaceFirst("^0","");
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//4654
```

Comment: Вы же говорите только один `0` может быть, а сами делаете на множество `0` =)

Comment: @And исправил , посмотрите)

Comment: Где? Ничего не поменялось.

Comment: @And ну так код который написал убирает только 1 ноль, лично у меня работает так как надо

Comment: Он убирает только один ноль, потому, что он только один, но это не значит, что выражение на один ноль. Логично?

Comment: @And нет, 0 может быть два , и убирает только один.

Comment: В вашем случае уберет все.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93293/discussion-between-kzz-xd-and-and).